# How can I find the number of users who visit my site via a redirect?

Tags: redirects, analytics, 301-redirect

My domain `foo.example` redirects (via a permanent 301) to `bar.example`. I want to know how many visitors to `bar.example` come from having first visited `foo.example`.

I'm using Woopra - originally, I thought the referrer would be `foo.example`, but it turns out that this is not the case. I'm fine with writing custom JS if that is required, but I have a pretty "user friendly" hosting account, which means that I can't really fiddle with Apache or whatever to log the redirects.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `/?utm_source=foo.com&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=301` This should do the trick !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a correctly done 301 redirect, as you've noticed, the referred will be the original referer, not the directed URL (`foo.example` in your example).

You should be able to see the 301 redirects to `bar.example` in the log files for your `foo.example` site.

If for some reason you can see the log files for your `foo.example` web server, then you could track them using Google Analytics.

In the 301 redirect, add [campaign tracking variables](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578) to the `bar.example` URL you are redirecting to, including foo (or whatever you fancy) as the campaign or source. Note that this will, of course, overwrite any earlier source attribution.

Make sure though that `bar.example` has [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in the head of it's pages, to avoid any problems of duplicate content.